# NullPointerException on MLDataSet. Partitioning of training and testing set on ENCOG

Tags: nullpointerexception, encog

I am new to ENCOG. We are developing a neural network and I have a problem on my generateTrainingData(). It gets a NullPointerException. Do you have any idea how to fix this? I think I have issue in giving specific value of TRAIN_END and EVAL_START. My input has a size of 1035.

```
//generates training set
public MLDataSet generateTrainingData(){
    TemporalMLDataSet result = new TemporalMLDataSet(WINDOW_SIZE, 24);

    TemporalDataDescription desc = new TemporalDataDescription(
            TemporalDataDescription.Type.RAW, true, true);
    result.addDescription(desc);

    for (int year = TRAIN_START; year < TRAIN_END; year++) {
        TemporalPoint point = new TemporalPoint(1);
        point.setSequence(year);
        point.setData(0, this.normalizeData[year]);
        result.getPoints().add(point);
    }

    result.generate();

    return result;
}
```